# Get Function Annotations from Parent Class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, annotations

Say I have the following situation:

```
abstract class Foo {

    abstract fun bar();

    fun baz() {
        println(this::bar.annotations)
    }

}

class Qux : Foo {

    @Annotation
    override fun bar() {
        ...
    }

}
```

When I try to implement this it does *not* get the annotations as defined in the child class, it gets them as defined in the parent class. If I remember correctly Java used to do the former, which is what I'm attempting to do here. My goal output is for it to print the `@Annotation` when `Qux#baz` is  run. Is this possible in kotlin?

Using `this::bar.javaClass.annotations` does fix it so I can see the annotation, however I then cannot get the type of the annotations using `is`, at least if I can I'm not entirely sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the original `println` line with the following fixed the issue:

```kotlin
...
    val method = this::class.java.getDeclaredMethod("bar")
    println(method.annotations)
...
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this fixes it? Only thing I can guess is this grabs the function at runtime, resulting in the child class's function, which is the one I want, rather than the statement being evaluated at compile time for the first one, which results in the parent class's function, or the one I don't want. I could be entirely wrong but this is just my guess